# Uploaded file from Html form to S3 using python but getting blank text file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an HTML form (implemented in Flask) for uploading files. And I want to store the uploaded files directly to S3.

The relevant part of the Flask implementation is as follows:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return '<form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="file" /><button>Upload</button></form>'
```

I then use boto3 to upload the file to S3 as follows:

```
@app.route('/upload',methods = ['GET','POST'])
    def upload_file():
        if request.method =='POST': 
            file = request.files['file']
            if file:
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                #file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER,filename))
                s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id='****',
                            aws_secret_access_key='*****')
                buck = s3_resource.Bucket('MY_BUCKET_NAME')
                buck.Object(file.filename).put(Body=file.read())

            return 'uploaded'
```

File is getting uploaded successfully in S3 Bucket. And when trying to open that file it is opening as blank text file. Even I tried to set `ContentType` in `put()` method but still not working.

Also its size is showing `0B`

[image]

Please let me know whats going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding debug code to the Python to show what is in the `file` variable?

Comment: Yes, `file`  variable is a `FileStroage` of selected file becuase I am using `Flask` framework. But s3's `put()` method accepts `file -like object` so I am using `file.read()`.

Comment: where else you have used the `file.read()`? can you show whole code?

Comment: An alternative approach would be to save the file to the `/tmp/` directory, then upload the file from disk. [flask.request.files Python Example](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/51528/flask.request.files)

Comment: @Debendra, I am using `file.read()` only to pass in `Body` attribute in `put()` method. I have updated full `/upload` route.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, it would be standard approach?

Comment: can you show me output of `file`?

Comment: value of file is `<FileStorage: 'FRIDAY_SALE_50_14.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>` , because variable is of type `werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.`

Comment: is there bytes when you  `file.read()`?

Comment: yes, its bytes.

Comment: can you `len(file.read())`? Show the output.

Comment: `2659` the length of bytes code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207919/discussion-between-debendra-and-saurabh-sharma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have certainly reached end of stream.

`file.read()` has no bytes to read, hence empty file on s3.

Either try `file.seek(0)` to reset the stream or you must ensure that you are reading file once.

For example:

```
# You just read the file here.
file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
# file.read() is empty now, you reached to the end of stream

# You are again reading the file here but file.read() is empty, so reset the stream.
file.seek(0)
# file.read() is back to original now
buck.Object(file.filename).put(Body=file.read())
```